# Multiple if statements with single else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm reviewing for an exam and although we have an answer key, I don't understand the correct answer.

```
if (score >= 90)
    grade = 'A';
if (score >= 80)
    grade = 'B';
if (score >= 70)
    grade = 'C';
if (score >= 60) 
    grade = 'D';
else 
    grade = ‘F’;
```

The answer key says that "This code will work correctly only if grade < 70". I know the else statement is linked with the last if-statement, but I'm still confused. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: Just do a manual trace, try mentally setting score to 80, then 70, then 60, and observe what happens during each

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Why does this code not work for the if-statements before it?

Comment: As ASKASK has stated, what happens with the code if `score` has a value of `100`? What is the final value of `grade`?

Comment: @user3453823 Step through it in your head. The output for 70 *should* be `C`. Is it?

Comment: Ahh I got it now. Thanks for the help. I think it was just the wording of the answer that threw me off.

Comment: The answer key should also probably say "score" and not "grade".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snippet you've posted is 4 independent, unrelated `if` statements, and the last one happens to have an `else` condition. Since the statements are all separate, if one of the conditions is true, that doesn't prevent the other if statements from executing as well.

In your snippet, if score was e.g. 95, then grade would be set to 'A', then overwritten by 'B', then by 'C', then by 'D' and would ultimately end up as 'D'. However, if the score was < 70, the results left over from the final `if` statement would coincide with the correct results, hence it only leaves `grade` with the correct results when `score < 70`.

The correct form would be:

```
if (score >= 90) grade = 'A';
else if (score >= 80) grade = 'B';
else if (score >= 70) grade = 'C';
else if (score >= 60) grade = 'D';
else grade = 'F';
```

If you try your code in a debugger with various inputs, and break on the first line, you can see exactly what is going on.

For more information, see [the official tutorial on `if-else` statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Comment: You did not show the correct record of this if statement.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Hmm, can you clarify? I am having trouble spotting the error.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. If the score is greater than 70, then the grade will be the last statement to run, so the last thing `grade` will be set to will always be 'D'. Thus, you need else if statements, or another technique, such as reversing all the if statements (ie putting `if score>= 90` last).